# How to store data in this very simple React Native app?

Tags: database, react-native, storage

I'm developing an app using React Native that allows you to create your own checklists and add items to them.

For example you'd have "Create Checklist", and inside that you'll have the option to "Add Item", "Delete Item" "Edit Item", basic CRUD methods etc.

It's going to be completely offline but I'm wondering what the best approach to storing this data locally would be.

Should I be using a DB such as firebase? I have read that it is overkill and to use something like Redux but I'm not sure if the latter will accomplish everything I need. As long as it's storing data which can be edited, and will save on the user's device (with minimal effort) it sounds good to me.

Would appreciate some input on this, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [AsyncStorage](https://github.com/react-native-async-storage/async-storage) for persisting data locally on the user's phone. It is a simple persistent key-value-storage.

Each checklist is most likely an array of JS objects. The documentation provides an example on how to store objects.

```js
const storeData = async (value) => {
  try {
    const jsonValue = JSON.stringify(value)
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('@storage_Key', jsonValue)
  } catch (e) {
    // saving error
  }
}
```

The `value` parameter is any JS object. We use `JSON.stringify` to create a JSON string. We use `AsyncStorage.setItem` in order to persist the data. The string `@storage_Key` is the key for the object. This could be any string.

We retrieve a persisted object as follows.

```js
const getData = async () => {
  try {
    const jsonValue = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@storage_Key')
    return jsonValue != null ? JSON.parse(jsonValue) : null;
  } catch(e) {
    // error reading value
  }
}
```

Both examples are taken from the [official documentation](https://react-native-async-storage.github.io/async-storage/docs/usage).

Keep in mind that this functionality should be used for `persistence only`. If the application is running, you should load the complete list, or parts of the list if it is very large, in some sort of application cache. The implementation for this functionality now heavily depends on how your current code looks like. If you have a plain view, then you could access the local storage in an effect and just store it in a local state.

```js
function MySuperList() {
   
   const [list, setList] = useState([]);

   React.useEffect(() => {
       // retrieve data using the above functionality and set the state
   }, [])

   // render list
   return (...)
}
```

I would implement some sort of `save button` for this list. If it is pressed, then we persist the data in the local storage of the phone.